# how to pass multiple flags in argparse python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to pass multiple flags, basically two flags. This is what my code looks like

```
parser.add_argument('--naruto', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--transformers', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--goku', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--anime', action='store_true')
```

I know action='store_true' makes it a flag. basically in the command line I will pass the arguments like => `nameOfTheScript.py --goku --anime` and based on this later on I will be checking if "anime" was sent as an argument do x else do y.
how can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Have you done `args=parser.parse_args()`?  When debugging I also suggest adding a `print(args)`.  You should now be able to do something like `if args.anime: print('do x')`.

Comment: @hpaulj it gives me an error on `parser.parse_args()` saying unrecognized arguments: --goku --anime

Comment: What's the `usage` that's displayed with the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your code should not give that error on `parser.parse_args()` if you have indeed added those arguments to `parser` and are specifying them in the command line. With the code you've shown, plus what @hpaulj suggested, I get the expected `Namespace(anime=True, goku=True, naruto=False, transformers=False)`

Comment: @hpaulj usage is `nameOfTheScript.py [--naruto] [--transformers] [--goku] [--anime]` 
when I put only one argument, for example only --goku, the script runs fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you ask how you can parse those args.
Here is an example of argument parsing:

```
parser.add_argument('--naruto', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--transformers', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--goku', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--anime', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

# You can access your args with dot notation
if args.goku:
  print("goku arg was passed in")

if args.anime:
  print("anime arg was passed in")
```

Comment: that's what I intend to do but it's giving me an error on `args = parser.parse_args()` saying unexpected arguments

Comment: How do you define a parser?

Comment: by parser = argparse.ArgumentParser

Comment: Maybe you could post the whole script from the beginning?

Comment: I am an idiot, sorry. I was debugging the code with launch.json file and the args should have been like this:
"--naruto", "--goku"
],
but I had set up args like this "--naruto --goku" which was causing the issue.

Comment: Got it, the issue is resolved then