# passing multiple flags in argparse?

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to pass multiple different flags using argparse. I know this kind of code would work for a single flag. if the -percentage flag is passed then do something

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-percentage', action='store_true')
```

but I'm trying to pass multiple flags, for example this code

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-serviceA', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-serviceB', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-serviceC', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-serviceD', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-activate', action='store_true')
```

and then pass flags -serivceB -activate, my intention is that the activate flag is basically a yes or no. and the service flag is the actual service. so that the service would get activated only when there is a activate flag next to it. how can I do this?
I hope i explained the situation in detail. please any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you should have the service flags take a string rather than trying to make these two different flags.

Comment: @Samwise can you give an example, please? I didn't get it

Comment: `args.serviceA` will True or False.  It's up to your own code to do something with that value.  `argparse` is done once you do `parse_args`

Comment: Other than the change in names, how's this different from the earlier question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646162/how-to-pass-multiple-flags-in-argparse-python

Comment: i.e. do `parser.add_argument('-serviceA')` and then check for `args.serviceA == "activate"`.

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging it wrong. I spent last 5 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks to everyone who mentioned the comment!

for anyone experiencing the same issue, when you are debugging using a launch.json file. make sure your args are like this "args": [
"--serviceA", "--activate"
],
I had set up args like this "--serviceA --activate"